# Passing a bag as an input for UDF in PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm trying to pass a databag(final) as an input.

```
 dump final;
```

gives:-

```
(4,john,john,David,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,Arkansasdest1,Destination)
(4,john,john,David,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,Arkanssdest2,Destination)
(4,johns,johns,David,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,ArkansasSrc1,source)
(4,johns,johns,David,Banking ,4,M,20-01-1994,78.65,345000,ArkansaSrc2,source)
```

I'm about to write an UDF for processing the above databag and finding mismatch between Source and Destination, in order to do that i have to check whether my UDF accepts databag or not. so i wrote one sample UDF below:

```
package PigUDFpck;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;


public class databag extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {
TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException { // different return type

    DataBag result = mBagFactory.newDefaultBag(); // change here
    DataBag values = (DataBag)input.get(0);
    for (Iterator<Tuple> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Tuple tuple = iterator.next();

        //logic
        Tuple t = mTupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();


        t.append(tuple);

        result.add(t);
    }
    return result; // change here
}

}
```

After that I registered the path using

```
REGISTER /usr/local/pig/UDF/UDFBAG.jar;
DEFINE Databag Databag(); // not sure how to define it
```

2017-02-16 19:07:05,875 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s). //got this warning after defining.

```
final1 = FOREACH final GENERATE(Databag(final));
```

ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
 Invalid scalar projection: final : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Please help me on Defining the UDF and how to pass a DataBag to UDF

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks good not sure why you are getting warning and error. Can you try to do one change in your for loop, instead of using iterator, use `for(Tuple tuple : values){ //you code }` . Also why you are creating new tuple for each row?

Comment: Hi Rajen, Could you please tell me the format of how to Define the UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
final1 = FOREACH final GENERATE(Databag(*));
```

Though as far as I see, your final contains tuples, not bags of tuples, so you'll probably need to first group it by some key. in that case it will be smth like

```
final1 = FOREACH (group final [by key or all]) GENERATE(Databag(final));
```